# Usage of では in this sentence

Tags: grammar, usage, particles, particle-で, sentence

I have read some topics about usage of では on the internet, like で for places, means, tools and は to mark the subject, argument,... However, I can't apply those to explain meaning of では in this sentence

> 今回の値上げは、原発事故の影響で、火力発展の燃料費が増加したことによるものだと東京電力**では**説明しています

As I understand, 東京電力 is Tokyo electric company and they are the one (the subject) explaining the reason why electric price is going up. Why do the writer add not only は but also で here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

は does not mark the subject; it marks the *topic*.  The topic can serve any other function in the sentence.  Often the *topic* is the *subject*.  But, it can also be the *object* (direct/indirect) of the verb.  は also can be used to mark contrast.

Notice, the topic is actually 値上げ, the increase in price.

With 東京電力では, the use of は adds a sense of contrast.  Various other electric companies might explain the increase in prices in other ways but here *at Tokyo Electric* the explanation is that which was quoted.

Comment: I understand what you said. But the main question I want to ask here is the role of で. I mean, で in this sentence is not pointing a place that something happens. or a means of transport, right? It confuses me at this point

Comment: @Mihara I'm not sure how native speakers would construe it.  But as I read it, an explanation was given at a certain place and that place happens to be *Tokyo Electric*.  This is not an uncommon sentence structure in Japanese where で is used to mark the source of the information (here *explanation*).

Comment: I understand. Thank you!!